# Crop and Overlay on a video simultaneously using JavaCV for Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I am using javacv version-1.1 on android studio and it is working perfectly.

I want to crop and apply overlay to a video using FFmpegFrameFilter. I am not an expert in ffmpeg commands so can you help me please to achieve it.

Overlay should be same size of the frame. I am able to crop but also wants an image overlay of the size of video frame.

Thanks